# Binary Relations that are Partial Orders

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to figure out the relationship between binary relations in a set and partial orders. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the answer is 19: http://oeis.org/A001035

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kaa1el is correct in the comments: this is [OEIS](http://oeis.org/wiki/Welcome) [A$001035$](http://oeis.org/A001035), and the desired term is $19$. Probably the easiest way to compute it by hand is to list the possible Hasse diagrams and count the possible relations for each. Here are the five possible Hasse diagrams:

```
  *    
  |  
  *         *   *            *             *  
  |          \ /            / \            |  
  *           *            *   *           *   *           *   *   *
```

There are $3!=6$ distinct partial orders with the first diagram, one for each permutation of $a,b$, and $c$ from top to bottom. A partial order on $\{a,b,c\}$ with the second diagram is completely determined when we know which element is at the bottom, so it accounts for just $3$ partial orders. Similarly, the third Hasse diagram accounts for $3$. The fourth again accounts for $6$: there are $3$ ways to choose the odd element and then $2$ ways to order the other two. Finally, the last Hasse diagram corresponds to just one partial order on $\{a,b,c\}$, equality. The total is then $6+3+3+6+1=19$.